# Change output in ipython while cell is running

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to get ipython to do the following?

```
#A cell...
output("a") # the cell output shows "a"
change_output("b") # the cell output now shows "b". "a" has been deleted
```

I want this behavior so that the cell output can display the current running state without lots of lines of output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
import sys
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
def change_output(x):
    clear_output()
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()

change_output("a")
change_output("b")
```